# I removed all the IOS simulators from my mac now I can't add any one

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I did something really stupid, I was playing around with Xcode 6 beta 2 and for some reason when I ran the simulator, I deleted all the available simulators, now I have no idea how do I install them again. Any help?

Comment: I have xcode 6 beta 2, again still no go

Comment: I don't have any back ups setted up, didn't think I need them 'till now.

Comment: Yes now I know to keep backups, I have uninstalled with clean my mac 2, and reinstalled again xcode it didn't re-install the sim.

Comment: You can add new simulators in Xcode 6, from the Devices window. See my answer below - you don't need to re-install Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments are mistaken: you don't need to re-install Xcode, you can just add new simulators. In the Devices window look for the plus button by the list of devices and simulators (which presumably will now be empty, as you have none). You can use this to add the simulators back in that you deleted.

**Step by Step Instructions**

Window > Devices, click + button at the very bottom left corner, click Add Simulator, choose the Device Type you want, and click Create.

Comment: Where are the devices window exactly?? Tkns.

Comment: In the Window->Devices menu

Comment: Thanks, I will never move it again :)